# Is the Workflow module a Symfony component?

Tags: 8, workflows

In Drupal 8.5, is the Workflow module a component from Symfony?

I ask because I thought it might help me to learn the basics from the Symfony Workflow component, but looking at the core directory and the composer.json file I saw this.

```
"symfony/class-loader": "~3.4.0",
"symfony/console": "~3.4.0",
"symfony/dependency-injection": "~3.4.0",
"symfony/event-dispatcher": "~3.4.0",
"symfony/http-foundation": "~3.4.14",
"symfony/http-kernel": "~3.4.14",
"symfony/routing": "~3.4.0",
"symfony/serializer": "~3.4.0",
"symfony/translation": "~3.4.0",
"symfony/validator": "~3.4.0",
"symfony/process": "~3.4.0",
"symfony/polyfill-iconv": "^1.0",
"symfony/yaml": "~3.4.5",
```

In the *replace* section, I noticed the following line.

```
"drupal/workflows": "self.version",
```

Comment: No, I think they are different

Answer (score 2):

No, the Workflow module is not a Symfony component.

As for what you found, the first list are the Drupal core dependencies, which include its dependencies from Symfony components.
Under the *replace* section, you just find a list of Drupal core modules. You can understand they are modules because they are listed as `drupal/<module machine name>`, while the [Workflow component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/workflow.html) would be listed as *symfony/workflow*.